# Login to Https Website with WebRequest and WebResponse Not Working C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, https, httpwebrequest

I am working on a program that will log into a website and get certian data. However I am having trouble posting the login parameters and dealing with the cookies, as each time I get a page saying "You have logged out or Session has expired." So clearly I'm doing something wrong with posting the parameters or dealing with the cookies, but don't know which. I have been working on this for a while and just can't get my head around why this is not working correctly.

```
void Login2(string username, string password)
    {
        string pageSource;
        string formUrl = "https://forUrl.com";
        string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&sslProt={1}&pwd={2}&gru={3}", username, "", password, "115237091");
        string cookieHeader;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        string getUrl = "https://Urlbehindform.com";   
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Method = "GET";
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Response.Redirect(getUrl);

    }
```

I am getting the cookie when I do the POST and sending it back when I do the GET, but for some reason this doesn't seem to work. At first I thought it was the parameters, but after looking at the issue further using Tamper Data with Firefox the login parameters seem to be working fine. Any help would be great, as I have been working on this for a while and can't wrap my head around it. Thanks!

*UPDATE*:

After trying out a few suggestions I still can't get this to work. However Upon looking deeper into Data Tamper, It appears that there is a POST with the login parameters, then a GET to a different page and then finally the GET to the page after the login page (The one I'm trying to get to). After some further debugging I actually discovered that my login POST is not working as I thought, As the response header location is showing "/cv/scripts/A028/eng/logErr.asp". Meaning the rest of my code could have been fine all a long, it was that the POST wasn't giving me a valid login. Any Sugguestions as to why I am always getting the login error page? As always thanks for the help.

*UPDATE*:

After playing around further with Tamper Data is appears that the reason I am unable to get a successful login is that in order have a successful POST of the parameters there needs to be a cookie already obtained. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The code seems correct. Just as an idea, I've had once such a problem. Add req.UserAgent="--get-a-real-user-agent-from-your-browser--". Some sites do some silly checks for that..

Answer (score 2):

Use a single [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) for both requests. Then you don't have to copy cookies manually.

I [BMW1] added in a CookieContainer called cookies, but it still not working, Im not sure if im using the CookieContainer the right way. Here is an updated version of my code.

And edited by me [Hans Kesting], see comments with [HK]

```
    void Login2(string username, string password)
    {
        string pageSource;
        string formUrl = "https://server/cv/scripts/A028/eng/logProc.asp?ntry=0&dbg=";
        string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&sslProt={1}&pwd={2}&gru={3}", username, "", password, "115237091");

        // [HK] create a container for the cookies, where they are added automatically
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        // [HK] no need to add cookies "by hand", that will happen automatically
        //cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);


        string getUrl = "https://server/cv/scripts/A028/eng/home.asp";
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        // [HK] use the same cookiecontainer as on the first request - correct
        getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies; 
        getRequest.Method = "GET";
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        // [HK] no need to add cookies, they should be there already
        //cookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // [HK] no need to add cookies, they should be there already
        // cookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);
        Response.Redirect(getUrl);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I am still not able to get to the page past the login. I am still getting the page for not being logged in and/or session timed out. Could it be possible that a session is needed to authenticate the login, meaning would a possible GET before I POST the parameters do anything? Once again thanks for the help. @Hans Kesting

Comment: @BMW1 - It's possible that you first need a session before you can login (I've seen that in a java environment). Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to really see what is sent/received.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cookie aware web client,

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient() : this (new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
    {
         (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
    }
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) request;
    httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
    String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

    if (setCookieHeader != null)
    {
        //do something if needed to parse out the cookie.
        if (setCookieHeader != null)
        {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
        this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var wc = new CookieAwareWebClient ();
wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
```